# $.Post() cross-domain request works in chrome console but not in html page request

Tags: jquery, asp.net, google-chrome, cross-domain, .post

I'm trying to send a $.post() cross-domain request.
This is what I'm doing:

```
$.post(
    "http://mysite.com/call.aspx/record",
    { Enroll : enroll, Item : item, usu : user, version :      
        version, video : flv64String },
    function(data){ console.log(data); return data; },
    "json"
)
```

This is what I have in the calling Webservice button function.

I'have configured my web.config with

```
 <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
```

So, when I click in the webservice caller button, the post is called and nothing happens. But when I paste the same $.post() method in Chrome console and properly change the variables with working values and execute, it works fine!

Now  I'm wondering, why the $.post works in Google Chrome console and in my site doesn't ?

I hope some one could answer me.

Comment: on google console, check the network what your page send, what replay is gets. Only with this informations you can find the reason of your issue